# How to add a stroke to only some characters in a string using PHP ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagick, stroke, text-rendering

Say I have the following code:

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw(); // prep text
$draw->setFillColor('#00ff00');
$draw->setFontSize(12);
$draw->setStrokeWidth(4);
$draw->setStrokeColor(new ImagickPixel('#ff0000'));
// etc.

$image = new Imagick(); // prep image
// etc.

// add text to image
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 10, 0, 'Hello, World!');
```

And let's assume that it works (which it does - I've just cut it down here). **Is there a simple way for me to, say, change the stroke width on a per-character basis?**

I'm looking into using something like `$image->queryFontMetrics($text, 'H'))` but wondered if there was a simpler way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw(); // prep text
$draw->setFillColor('#00ff00');
$draw->setFontSize(12);
$draw->setStrokeColor(new ImagickPixel('#ff0000'));
// etc.

$image = new Imagick(); // prep image
// etc.

// add text to image
$draw->setStrokeWidth(4);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 10, 0, 'He');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(5);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 12, 10, 0, 'llo, ');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(6);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 15, 10, 0, 'Wor');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(7);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 18, 10, 0, 'ld!');
```

Would something like that work or would that be too clunky? It could work if the string was always the same and you figured out what the $x dimensions were correctly (the 2nd parameter in the annotateImage() function)

Comment: I see that `$image->queryFontMetrics($text, 'H'))` is what you were meaning to use for the character width in the string. Id suggest thats probably going to be the most effective way to get the right $x dimension